# Unable to scrape image url from meta tags for facebook ads - Axios Cheerio

Tags: facebook, axios, cheerio, scrape

Thanks for stopping by.

I am trying to scrape the value for `og:image` meta tag from a facebook ad URL using Axios and Cheerio. I have a function for this that gets called inside the context of a deployed api (aws)

Testing locally the function that does this job has no problems, it works fine using both: postman and having the api deployed locally, or just by invoking the function with `node`.

Problem happens when testing with postman on the deployed api. The axios `responseUrl` is an encoded 'login kind of' url, but yet contains the url for the ad I am looking for:

Example: `https://www.facebook.com/login/?next=...` where `...` contains the encoded ad url.

There are 2 catches:

1. The provided url to the function is shortened and GET requests with axios obtain redirects to a different URL (the one containing the actual ad). Axios `responseUrl` doesn't match the provided url. (This is already handled, so no problem)
2. When testing the function in the deployed api with Postman, the axios `responseUrl` always responds with an encoded url that asks to login and contains as well the actual ad url (decodeURIComponent the url and spliting the string to get the actual ad url handles this fine

I can get the actual ad url in any case, but when making a GET request with axios to the correct, decoded ad url to then parse it with cheerio, I get the same url as described on item 2.

Thanks in advance for any advice or suggestion regarding axios or facebook scrapping

This is my code (logs left for debbuging)

```js
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const axios = require('axios')

const timeout = 3000
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  timeout: timeout
})

async function getImageURL(url) {

  //eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log('getImageUrl fn invoked for arg url:', url)

  if (!url) {
    return null
  } else {
    try {

      // Gets url html content

      let axiosResponse = await axiosInstance.get(url)

      //eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log(
        'axiosResponse.request.res.responseUrl: >>',
        axiosResponse.request.res.responseUrl
      )

      // Check for redirects: perform a new get to redirected url

      while (url !== axiosResponse.request.res.responseUrl) {

        //eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('>>>>> inside while loop <<<<<')

        //eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log(
          'url equals responseUrl ?',
          url === axiosResponse.request.res.responseUrl
        )

        axiosResponse = await axiosInstance.get(
          axiosResponse.request.res.responseUrl
        )

        url = axiosResponse.request.res.responseUrl
      }

      //eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log('\n =========== outside while loop ======= \n')

      //eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log(
        'url equals responseUrl ?',
        url === axiosResponse.request.res.responseUrl
      )

      //eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log(
        'axiosResponse.request.res.responseUrl: >>',
        axiosResponse.request.res.responseUrl
      )

      // Check for encoded url with requiring to login

      if (url.includes('login')) {
        //eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log(`\nContains 'login'. Last GET performed to: ${url}\n`)

        const decodedURL = decodeURIComponent(url).split('next=')[1]
        //eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('decodedURL', decodedURL)

        axiosResponse = await axiosInstance.get(decodedURL)
      }

      const data = axiosResponse.data

      // Loads HTML to then parse image url

      const $ = cheerio.load(data)
      const metaTags = []

      $('meta').each(function (i) {
        metaTags[i] = $(this).attr()
      })

      //eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log('meta tags elements with their attributes >>', metaTags)

      const imageURL = $("meta[property='og:image']").attr('content')

      //eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log('obtained imageURL: ', imageURL)

      return imageURL ? imageURL : 'Url could not be parsed'

    } catch (error) {
      //eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.error('Error getImageURL: ', error.message)
      return null
    }
  }
}

module.exports = getImageURL

// this last part only when testing the function with node

async function main() {
  await getImageURL('insert your facebook ad url here')

main()
```

Comment: Sorry, what site are we scraping here? Do you have an example encoded ad URL?

Comment: Hi! Its a shortened url from a facebook ad. An example: h t t p s ://f b.me/dMhvNJNlP

The enconded URL I get from the axios response to the above url, after redirects are handled, is the following: https://www.facebook.com/login/?next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fstory.php%3Fstory_fbid%3Dpfbid0c14oJSskq4emfgd7dQPGXQpjR9csoB1Qvvt4xCFRUecGP3AucteU8v78AMCCjN9Rl%26id%3D104657498072776%26post_id%3D104657498072776_pfbid0c14oJSskq4emfgd7dQPGXQpjR9csoB1Qvvt4xCFRUecGP3AucteU8v78AMCCjN9Rl

The correct URL to the actual ad that should GET axios is encoded there after the next=